# Reset badge counter for push notifications using Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com for an iOS app with push notification. I just sent a message to all the users with the Badge Increment option.

Now when you open the app, the badge doesn't clear.

Any idea how to reset the badge counter to zero?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following. It should do the trick. This will reset the badge to 0 when you open the app.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
  if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
    currentInstallation.badge = 0;
    [currentInstallation saveEventually];
  }
  // ...
}
```